# How to check if user is part of an AD group? (even group within a group)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, active-directory-group

I need to check if users logging into the console application I am making are part of a DL (let's call it DL-A).

Some users aren't directly part of DL-A, but of other DLs that are a member of DL-A. The code that I have working only checks the groups of which the user is directly a member of. How do I check this?

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "DL-A");

if (user != null)
{
   if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can see if the user is a member of a nested group is get all the users from a group `recursively`. I am using `user` and `group` from your code:

```
....

if (group != null)
{
    var users = group.GetMembers(true); //this will get nested users
    var contains = users.Contains(user);
    if (contains)
    {
       //user found
    }
}

...
```